# SQL Case Statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named as "allocation" with the columns named as "all_code", "grs_amt" and "cut_amt". I want to create a SQL statement to be got results as Gross_Value, Cut_Value and Net_Value. If the "cut_amt" IsNull then assign 0 for the Cut_Value and then calculate Net_Value using that assigned 0 value or available value in the "cut_amt".  I used the following query.

```
SELECT allocation.grs_amt AS Gross_Value,
  IfNull(allocation.cut_amt, 0) AS Cut_Value,
  allocation.grs_amt - allocation.cut_amt AS Net_Value FROM
  allocation
```

02) But unable to get the desired output. Can not understand what I am going wrong . Can anyone help me?

Comment: I used MySQL for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to repeat the expression:

```
SELECT a.grs_amt AS Gross_Value,
       coalesce(a.cut_amt, 0) AS Cut_Value,
       (a.grs_amt - coalesce(a.cut_amt, 0)) AS Net_Value
FROM allocation a;
```

I prefer `coalesce()` under most circumstances because it is ANSI standard.